# How to find which hospital is under which block using R?

Tags: r, location, geospatial, spatial

I had a list of addresses which i geocoded to find their latitude and longitude.
The addresses had two entities block names and hospitals.
I have the list of latlong for both of them.Now I want to find out which hospital is under which block? How to accomplish that?
I am putting some entries from the list so that understandability can be improved, the original lists have about 100 entries for each block and hospitals.

```
    Blocks List

    address lat long    accuracy
    Ajabpur 30.0431765  78.8255226  locality
    UHC Ajabpur 30.0431765  78.8255226  locality
    Asan Bag    30.5829083  77.7523608  locality
    Ashtad  30.6865869  77.8453043  locality
    Badripur    30.2843949  78.0656264  sublocality_level_1
    Balawala    30.2661801  78.1062092  sublocality_level_1

    Hospitals List
    hospitals   lat long    accuracy
    CHC Chakrata    30.7016208  77.8695996  locality
    PHC Tuni    30.066753   79.0192997  administrative_area_level_1
    SC- Bayala  30.7540332  77.7509303  locality
    SAD Bulhar  30.066753   79.0192997  administrative_area_level_1
    SAD Hatal   30.066753   79.0192997  administrative_area_level_1
    SAD Lakhwar 30.5345496  77.9610158  locality
```

Comment: Are you just trying to do an exact match with `lat` and `long` ?

Comment: @steveb I am not trying an exact match but I am looking forward to create a polygon buffer region around a block and locate the hospital which falls under the polygon buffer but I am new to R so I am not aware about how to do it

Comment: like I said in your previous question look into gbuffer() and over(); just need to create polygons and use over() to see in which polygons your hospital fall in

Comment: @MLavoie the spatial dataframe you have asked me to create, it should be a spatial polygon data frame right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is something to get you started. Here is a great resource for `over()` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/over.pdf).

First, you create a buffer (`gbuffer()`) (polygon) for your data_table data sets. You can change the size of the buffer. You also need to turn your data_hop dataset into a spatial dataframe. Now you need to verify if your points fall into the +zone=47 and make sure you have the right epsg:24047 (http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/indian-1975-utm-zone-47n/). I don't get the output I would like but I noticed you have exactly the same coordinates for some of your blocks. Please make you sure to fix this.

Hope this code will help you to get you want!

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(geosphere)
library(rgeos)

data_table <- read.table(text="
add         lat         long
Ajabpur     30.0431765  78.8255226
UHCAjabpur  30.0431765  78.8255226
AsanBag    30.5829083  77.7523608
Ashtad      30.6865869  77.8453043
Badripur    30.2843949  78.0656264
Balawala    30.2661801  78.1062092
Ballupur    30.3335862  78.0115041
Barontha    30.066753   79.0192997",
    header = TRUE)
#    
data_hop <- read.table(text="
    hospitals   lat long    accuracy
    CHCChakrata    30.7016208  77.8695996  locality
    PHCTuni    30.066753   79.0192997  administrative_area_level_1
    SC-Bayala  30.7540332  77.7509303  locality
    SADBulhar  30.066753   79.0192997  administrative_area_level_1
    SADHatal   30.066753   79.0192997  administrative_area_level_1
    SADLakhwar 30.5345496  77.9610158  locality",
    header = TRUE)
#    
coordinates(data_table) <- ~ long + lat 
proj4string(data_table) <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=47 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")
pc <- spTransform(data_table, CRS( "+init=epsg:24047"))
pc10m <- gBuffer(pc, width=10, byid=TRUE)
#
coordinates(data_hop) <- ~ long + lat 
proj4string(data_hop) <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=47 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84")
WWc <- spTransform(data_hop, CRS("+init=epsg:24047")) 
#
testb <- over(WWc, pc10m, returnList = TRUE) #will return a list
test <- over(WWc, pc10m)
#
data_hop2 <- data_hop@data
finalb <- cbind(data_hop2, test)

> finalb
    hospitals                    accuracy     add
1 CHCChakrata                    locality Ajabpur
2     PHCTuni administrative_area_level_1 Ajabpur
3   SC-Bayala                    locality Ajabpur
4   SADBulhar administrative_area_level_1 Ajabpur
5    SADHatal administrative_area_level_1 Ajabpur
6  SADLakhwar                    locality Ajabpur
```

Comment: Thank you @MLavoie I read about gbuffer but I have just one little query, what is the dimension of the width parameter, is it in metres?

Comment: yes it's in meter, you can change the number as you wish.